# How to properly convert a variable byte of an array to list[int] in flask?

Tags: python, angular, flask

I have this flask code wherein it can receive an inputted `data` from the client side(angular). Example of the passed data into the flask is this `[23410, 23910, 25609, 23145, 22115]`. These passed data can be read in flask by this code `request.data` but this code only stored the passed data into bytes. So I tried to convert these passed data from bytes to list[int] using `dataConvert = list(data)` but the output was `[90, 50, 40, 70, 60, 80, 50, 20, 30, 60, 40....]` instead of `[23410, 23910, 25609, 23145, 22115]`. In summary how can I properly convert a variable byte into `list[int]`? or maybe how can I properly request a data so that it will store those passed data into `list[int]` automatically

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, redirect, request, url_for
import flask;
import pickle
import numpy as np
import flask
from flask_cors import CORS
from app import pred_dataout;

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

TAG =" ============>>>>>>>>"

@app.route("/adminData", methods = ['POST'])
def reportData():
    data = request.data
    dataConvert = list(data)// this is problem, I dont know how to properly convert a variable byte into list[int]
    print(TAG, data)
    return jsonify("ello")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you're sending a payload using **POST** request, your data is in **dictionary**, not in **list** so if the assumed payload you're sending is

```
{'values':[23410, 23910, 25609, 23145, 22115]}
```

then your **Flask** view would be something like this:

```
from flask import Flask, json, jsonify, request, make_response

@app.route("/adminData", methods = ['POST'])
def reportData():
    status = 200 # default success
    try:
        data = request.json # Read json dictionary from request
        values = data.get("values", None) # Get list from payload

        if values:
            result = {"message": "success", "values": values}
        else:
            status = 500 # Failure
            result = {"message": "error", "values": []}
    except Exception as e:
        status = 500 # Failure
        result = {"message": "error", "values": []}
    return make_response(jsonify(result), status)
```